# How optimize SQL query with DISTINCT ON and JOIN many values?

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-optimization

I have a query like this where join ~6000 values

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON(user_id)
                user_id,
                finished_at as last_deposit_date,
                CASE When currency = 'RUB' Then amount_cents  END as last_deposit_amount_cents
            FROM    payments
            JOIN (VALUES (5),(22),(26)) --~6000 values
            AS v(user_id) USING (user_id)
            WHERE action = 'deposit' 
                AND success = 't'
                AND currency IN ('RUB')
            ORDER BY user_id, finished_at DESC
```

QUERY PLAN for query with many VALUES:

```
Unique  (cost=444606.97..449760.44 rows=19276 width=24) (actual time=6129.403..6418.317 rows=5991 loops=1)
  Buffers: shared hit=2386527, temp read=7807 written=7808
  ->  Sort  (cost=444606.97..447183.71 rows=1030695 width=24) (actual time=6129.401..6295.457 rows=1877039 loops=1)
        Sort Key: payments.user_id, payments.finished_at DESC
        Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 62456kB
        Buffers: shared hit=2386527, temp read=7807 written=7808
        ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.43..341665.35 rows=1030695 width=24) (actual time=0.612..5085.376 rows=1877039 loops=1)
              Buffers: shared hit=2386521
              ->  Values Scan on "*VALUES*"  (cost=0.00..75.00 rows=6000 width=4) (actual time=0.002..4.507 rows=6000 loops=1)
              ->  Index Scan using index_payments_on_user_id on payments  (cost=0.43..54.78 rows=172 width=28) (actual time=0.010..0.793 rows=313 loops=6000)
                    Index Cond: (user_id = "*VALUES*".column1)
                    Filter: (success AND ((action)::text = 'deposit'::text) AND ((currency)::text = 'RUB'::text))
                    Rows Removed by Filter: 85
                    Buffers: shared hit=2386521
Planning time: 5.886 ms
Execution time: 6429.685 ms
```

I use PosgreSQL 10.8.0. Is there any chance to speed up this query?

I tried replacing DISTINCT with recursion:

```
WITH RECURSIVE t AS (
 (SELECT min(user_id) AS user_id FROM payments)
 UNION ALL
 SELECT (SELECT min(user_id) FROM payments  
 WHERE user_id > t.user_id      
 ) AS user_id FROM
t   
  WHERE t.user_id IS NOT NULL
 )
SELECT payments.* FROM t
JOIN (VALUES (5),(22),(26)) --~6000 VALUES
AS v(user_id) USING (user_id)
, LATERAL (
 SELECT user_id,
        finished_at as last_deposit_date,
        CASE When currency = 'RUB' Then amount_cents  END as last_deposit_amount_cents FROM payments            
        WHERE payments.user_id=t.user_id
            AND action = 'deposit' 
        AND success = 't'
        AND currency IN ('RUB')     
        ORDER BY finished_at DESC LIMIT 1
) AS payments

WHERE t.user_id IS NOT NULL;
```

But it turned out even **slower**.

> Hash Join  (cost=418.67..21807.22 rows=3000 width=24) (actual time=16.804..10843.174 rows=5991 loops=1)
>     Hash Cond: (t.user_id = "*VALUES*".column1)
>     Buffers: shared hit=6396763
>     CTE t
>       ->  Recursive Union  (cost=0.46..53.73 rows=101 width=8) (actual time=0.142..1942.351 rows=237029 loops=1)
>             Buffers: shared hit=864281
>             ->  Result  (cost=0.46..0.47 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.141..0.142 rows=1 loops=1)
>                   Buffers: shared hit=4
>                   InitPlan 3 (returns $1)
>                     ->  Limit  (cost=0.43..0.46 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.138..0.139 rows=1 loops=1)
>                           Buffers: shared hit=4
>                           ->  Index Only Scan using index_payments_on_user_id on payments payments_2  (cost=0.43..155102.74 rows=4858092 width=8) (actual time=0.137..0.138 rows=1 loops=1)
>                                 Index Cond: (user_id IS NOT NULL)
>                                 Heap Fetches: 0
>                                 Buffers: shared hit=4
>             ->  WorkTable Scan on t t_1  (cost=0.00..5.12 rows=10 width=8) (actual time=0.008..0.008 rows=1 loops=237029)
>                   Filter: (user_id IS NOT NULL)
>                   Rows Removed by Filter: 0
>                   Buffers: shared hit=864277
>                   SubPlan 2
>                     ->  Result  (cost=0.48..0.49 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.007..0.007 rows=1 loops=237028)
>                           Buffers: shared hit=864277
>                           InitPlan 1 (returns $3)
>                             ->  Limit  (cost=0.43..0.48 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.007..0.007 rows=1 loops=237028)
>                                   Buffers: shared hit=864277
>                                   ->  Index Only Scan using index_payments_on_user_id on payments payments_1  (cost=0.43..80786.25 rows=1619364 width=8) (actual time=0.007..0.007 rows=1 loops=237028)
>                                         Index Cond: ((user_id IS NOT NULL) AND (user_id > t_1.user_id))
>                                         Heap Fetches: 46749
>                                         Buffers: shared hit=864277
>     ->  Nested Loop  (cost=214.94..21498.23 rows=100 width=32) (actual time=0.475..10794.535 rows=167333 loops=1)
>           Buffers: shared hit=6396757
>           ->  CTE Scan on t  (cost=0.00..2.02 rows=100 width=8) (actual time=0.145..1998.788 rows=237028 loops=1)
>                 Filter: (user_id IS NOT NULL)
>                 Rows Removed by Filter: 1
>                 Buffers: shared hit=864281
>           ->  Limit  (cost=214.94..214.94 rows=1 width=24) (actual time=0.037..0.037 rows=1 loops=237028)
>                 Buffers: shared hit=5532476
>                 ->  Sort  (cost=214.94..215.37 rows=172 width=24) (actual time=0.036..0.036 rows=1 loops=237028)
>                       Sort Key: payments.finished_at DESC
>                       Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
>                       Buffers: shared hit=5532476
>                       ->  Index Scan using index_payments_on_user_id on payments  (cost=0.43..214.08 rows=172 width=24) (actual time=0.003..0.034 rows=15 loops=237028)
>                             Index Cond: (user_id = t.user_id)
>                             Filter: (success AND ((action)::text = 'deposit'::text) AND ((currency)::text = 'RUB'::text))
>                             Rows Removed by Filter: 6
>                             Buffers: shared hit=5532473
>     ->  Hash  (cost=75.00..75.00 rows=6000 width=4) (actual time=2.255..2.255 rows=6000 loops=1)
>           Buckets: 8192  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 275kB
>           ->  Values Scan on "*VALUES*"  (cost=0.00..75.00 rows=6000 width=4) (actual time=0.004..1.206 rows=6000 loops=1)
>   Planning time: 7.029 ms
>   Execution time: 10846.774 ms

Answer (score 1):

For this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (user_id)
       p.user_id,
       p.finished_at as last_deposit_date,
       (CASE WHEN p.currency = 'RUB' THEN p.amount_cents  END) as last_deposit_amount_cents
FROM payments p JOIN
     (VALUES (5),( 22), (26) --~6000 values
     ) v(user_id)
     USING (user_id)
WHERE p.action = 'deposit' AND
      p.success = 't' ND
      p.currency = 'RUB'
ORDER BY p.user_id, p.finished_at DESC;
```

I don't fully understand the `CASE` expression, because the `WHERE` is filtering out all other values.

That said, I would expect an index on `(action, success, currency, user_id, finished_at desc)` to be helpful.